# Issue with systemd: several critical services failed

Tags: linux, systemd

I've discovered I have an issue with systemd on my Debian server.
I've seen that some logging service don't want to start through systemd but the daemon itself start without issues:

```
❯ systemctl start rsyslog.service
A dependency job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

If I start manually rsyslogd, it's working:

```
❯ /usr/sbin/rsyslogd

❯ ps awx | grep rsyslog
  45995 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

So I tried to understand what's wrong with systemd.

First, `journalctl -xe` shows only lines from 24 Oct, nothing recent.

I've tried `timedatectl` to ensure the date is correct but got this message

```
❯ timedatectl
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I've searched a lot on Internet and ended up running `systemctl --failed` command and it shown many failed services:

```
❯ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● dbus.socket                     loaded failed failed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
● syslog.socket                   loaded failed failed Syslog Socket
● systemd-fsckd.socket            loaded failed failed fsck to fsckd communication Socket
● systemd-journald-audit.socket   loaded failed failed Journal Audit Socket
● systemd-journald-dev-log.socket loaded failed failed Journal Socket (/dev/log)
● systemd-journald.socket         loaded failed failed Journal Socket
● systemd-udevd-control.socket    loaded failed failed udev Control Socket
● systemd-udevd-kernel.socket     loaded failed failed udev Kernel Socket
● uuidd.socket                    loaded failed failed UUID daemon activation socket

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
9 loaded units listed.
```

I've re-installed systemd-sysv and rebooted, cleaned old journalctl entries but same issues.

Basically, I'm clueless here :/
If someone have an idea :D

PS: I know it's christmas, I don't expect answers right now as I will also have some delays in answers ;)